# Remove entity when removed from collection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I have been trying to figure out why a column in my database was being set to null. I traced it down to entityframework, that when you remove an item from a collection it was not removed from the database just set the relationship column to null. I found a solution which is below, but seems far from ideal is there any other solution.

Thanks

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassAttendance>().HasKey( x => new
            {
                x.Id,
                x.ClassDefinitionId
            } );
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassAttendance>().Property( x => x.Id ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity );
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassDefinition>().HasMany( x => x.Attendances ).WithRequired().HasForeignKey( c => c.ClassDefinitionId ).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you have above is fine if it works. Another option you might look into is marking the object for deletion:

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

This will ensure that the record gets deleted from the database when you commit your changes to the database.

**EDIT**
You would need to tweak the logic a little bit to suit your implementation, but you could also look at rolling your own extension method to take care of marking the entity for deletion in the change tracker:

```
public static void Delete<TEntity> Delete<TEntity>(this IRepository repository, Func<IRepository, TEntity> selector)
{
    repository.MarkEntityState(selector(repository), EntityState.Deleted);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a bit of a work around and would make code a bit messy. Is this the only solution

Comment: I assume you are doing a commit after removing the item from the collection right? I would try to track down the entry in the change tracker after removing it from the collection and see if the state gets changed to `Deleted` or `Detached`. EF should be smart enough to delete the record if configured correctly.